# Extend ListViewItem in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've made a fatal mistake.

I totally forgot to extend the ListView to include some important features. And now it's way too late to just delete the ListView, add those features and re-add the ListView all over again.

What I need to add is simple, and I've done it before, but I don't think I can do it the same way as before because when I did it before I did it before I created the ListView and placed it on the Form.

I need to be able to do:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.SomeNewProperty = "yay";
```

But how can I extend the functionality now that I've already created a ListView control and added it to the form and set all of its properties and setup all of the events. If I delete the ListView and extend it then re-add it everything will be lost and I'd have to start over again.

Is there a way to extend it to add that new property to ListViewItem without starting from scratch?

Comment: As long as you're creating a subclass of `ListView`, all you really need to do is open the [Form].Designer.cs and change the declaration from `private ListView blah;` to `private YourCustomListView blah;`.

Comment: @helrich Oh, my heart is beating normally again. Thank you. :-)

Comment: No problem. You'll also need to update the line where the control is initialized with the new type, and for the new control to show in the designer, you'll need to build the project after the swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each control in `System.Windows.Form` contain a property called `Tag`, that is an `Object` DataType, if you just want to save one value in each `ListViewItem` you should do the following:

```
ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem();
Item.Tag = "Something";
```

But if you want to save multiple values in each `ListViewItem` you can create a class that contain all the info thet you want to set. Ex.

```
public class MyClass 
{
     public string Value1 {get; set;}
     public string Value2 {get; set;}
}

MyClass oInfo = new MyClass();
oInfo.Value1 = "Smething";
oInfo.Value2 = "Is Good";
ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem();
Item.Tag = oInfo;
```

To retrieve the object do the following:

```
 MyClass oRetrieveInfo  =  (MyClass)LisView.Items[index].Tag;
 MessageBox.Show(oRetrieveInfo.Value1 + " " + RetrieveInfo.Value2);
```